# Can node prevent an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Since node runs a single threaded model with event looping I wonder how node prevents the entire application to fail if you write a code like:

```
while(true){ doSomething()}
```

where doSomething is a synchronous function (a blocking piece of code)

Note that it doesn't make any sense to write a function like doSomething but nothing prevents you to make a mistake

The problem here is that, since it's single threaded, it won't allow any other parts of the application to run (for instance, a web server would stop accepting new connections) because this function would never end. In a Multi threaded environment you would loose this thread alone.

Is there anything that node can do for you to prevent these kind of problems?

Comment: It's not possible to prevent infinite loops - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: What makes you think that example would *not* loop indefinitely?

Comment: @MrDiggles this doesn't mean it would be impossible to prevent _some_ infinite loops. I'd however assume node does nothing of the sorts. Just start it and look at process explorer to make certain.

Comment: why is there so many negative comments on vote on this ? dont be too rude people.. you are not supposed to have a car accident when you are on the road, is it a reason to unplug the safety belt. stack overflow is not a site about opinions, it s a Q/A site.

Comment: @NicoAD thank you ! Too much negativity in this world ... too much !

Comment: well, some support, thanks. Actually voting down states the following "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Is this actually the case? I believe I hurt some people's feelings just by pointing something out that it's true. I only tried to see if something can be done about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder how node prevents the entire application to fail if you write an infinite loop

nodejs does not prevent such an infinite loop.  It will just run that loop forever or until some resource is exhausted (if the loop is consuming some resource like memory).

> If node can't prevent this kind of situations, is this a design fault or there's no way to prevent these kind of problems?

I don't think most people consider it a design fault - though that's purely an opinion and different people may have a different opinion.  It is a consequence of the way nodejs was designed which has many other benefits.

The only way to prevent such problems is to not write faulty code that does this.  Honestly, it's not too hard to avoid writing this type of code once you're aware that it's an issue to avoid.

> The problem here is that, since it's single threaded, it won't allow any other parts of the application to run (for instance, a web server would stop accepting new connections) because this function would never end. In a Multi threaded environment you would loose this thread alone

Correct.  This is something you learn when coding in nodejs.  I've never found it a hard thing to avoid.  nodejs is an single-threaded event driven system, not a multi-threaded system.  As such, you program with events, not long running loops that poll or check conditions.  It is a rather straightforward concept to learn and use once you understand this is how nodejs works.  It is different than some other environments.  But, how to use asynchronous operations in nodejs is just something you have to learn to program in that environment.  It's not avoidable and is just part of the character of nodejs.  There is no way that nodejs could have the type of architecture it has without having to learn this to program in it.  If you want a different architecture (for whatever personal reason), then pick a different environment, not nodejs.

The single-threadedness massively simplifies many other things (far, far fewer opportunities for race conditions) and improves scalability in some circumstances (with asynchronous I/O) vs. threaded environments.  For situations where you want multiple CPUs to be applied to your problem, it is generally straightforward in node.js to either use the built-in clustering module or to fire up worker processes and feed them work.  Data is often shared among multiple processes via some sort of database (either file-based or RAM-based) that handles much of the multi-process synchronization for you.

Comment: "Honestly, it's not too hard to avoid writing this type of code". sure , but it happens sometimes , I wrote code leading to an infinite loop in a specific and rare case. hangs on the server starts to occurs a long time after the faulty code was introduced before the issue is rare. I know we could have avoid this by unit tests, code review etc... but something issue like this happen so i m looking for solution for this. thanks to remote debug/inspect/ breakpoints for helping us on this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. This seems like less of a question and more an open statement. Node will loop infinitely and all your parallel code will stop running.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to find such issue in the node.js program itself. however a node.js script with an infinite loop will use lead to 100% cpu . so this can be monitored and you can use tools to restart the program. I don't recommand to do this, you should fix your infinite loop first, but it s sometimes hard to find the issue with large codebase. last time it happened to be I used a remote debugger to find the infinite loop.